# Setting x frame option header in GCS Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bucket

I have to set X-Frame Options in my application, i have hosted my application in GCS bucket. Please let me know how i can set header in bucket.

I am unable to figure it out where to set header in GCS bucket

Expecting application to run with X-Frame Options header set to deny.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand in your question, you want to set headers in the objects that you already have in the bucket. You can do that by running `gsutil setmeta -h "Header Info: Blah" gs://your-bucket-name/file-name.html` You can check more [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/setmeta)

Answer (score 0):

I found to do work around with meta data in GCS bucket. But some how i found that in GCS we will not be able to set security headers. we mailed them regarding the same they wrote us back saying these things are in there pipeline/future scope.
Hence we need to wait for sometime to get this onboarded in gcs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a load balancer to the backend bucket, you can try setting the header using the below commands:

```
gcloud compute backend-buckets list # To list the backend buckets
gcloud compute backend-buckets update <backend bucket name> --custom-response-header='X-Frame-Options: DENY'
```